When did Prophet Moses speak to prophet Adam?
The conversation between Prophet moses and Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) is well documented during the meraj of Prophet Muhammad (pbuh).
Did the following conversation take place on meraj of prophet moses?

The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Adam and Moses argued with each other. Moses said to Adam. 'O Adam! You are our father who disappointed us and turned us out of Paradise.' Then Adam said to him, 'O Moses! Allah favored you with His talk (talked to you directly) and He wrote (the Torah) for you with His Own Hand. Do you blame me for action which Allah had written in my fate forty years before my creation?' So Adam confuted Moses, Adam confuted Moses," the Prophet (ﷺ) added, repeating the Statement three times.

Sahih al-Bukhari 6614

The scholars have listed the following possibilities:

The event happened during the lifetime of Moses عليه السلام - Allah made it possible for him to see and speak with Adam. He might have resurrected Adam, or it could be that He showed him Adam's spirit, or it could have been inside a dream as the dreams of prophets are revelation.

أن عمر بن الخطاب، قال قال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم إن موسى قال يا رب أرنا آدم
Umar b. al-Khattab reported the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) as saying : Moses said : My lord, show us Adam ...
— Abu Dawud


It happened after the death of Moses عليه السلام when his spirit met the spirit of Adam.

The event has not happened yet, it will happen on the Day of Judgement.

It is a parable.


Ref: Fath al-Bari
